# Binding a dynamic property on a store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

From reading [the documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html), I need to add a two-way computed property to bind data from my form to the store. But I need to bind to an item on the object:

```
checked: {
    'football': [],
    'tennis': [],
    'rugby': [],
},
```

Under computed:

```
testBinding: {
        get () {
            return this.$store.state.Sports.checked;
        },
        set (value) {
            this.$store.commit('Sports/checked', value);
        }
    },
```

Inside my looped out checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" :value="option.id" v-model="testBinding">
```

How do I bind to something like `football` on the store, when `football` needs to be dynamically set in the binding, something like `v-model="testBinding[key]"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare *getters* and *setters* for the properties that you want to be dynamic. Computed properties **will not work** as you cannot pass parameters to them. You can define `football` like this on your `checked` data object

```
checked: {
 get football () {
    return this.$store.state.Sports.checked;
 },
 set football (value) {
    this.$store.commit('Sports/checked', value);
 }
 'tennis': [],
 'rugby': [],
},
```

And should be able to bind to it

```
<input type="checkbox" :value="option.id" v-model="checked['football']">
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" :value="option.id" v-model="checked.football">
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" :value="option.id" v-model="checked[var]">
```

where `var` is a variable with a value of `football`.

Here's [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pa2h0ur/) with getters and setters, but no [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).